# Vim default color scheme can't change

Tags: vim

I'm wondering why my VIM can't apply the changes I modify in `$MYVIMRC`. The changes only apply to GVIM instead of VIM. I have the following in `$MYVIMRC`:

```
syntax on
colorscheme tomorrow-night
```

I also tried changing the color scheme setting in the command bar below by typing `:colorscheme tomorrow-night` but nothing changed. Why is it not changing?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between Vim and GVim is that GVim is an independent application that does not run in your terminal emulator.

If you use Vim and GVim for different purposes, I recommend you to create also a `gvimrc` file. But if you want to keep a single `vimrc` file, you can do something like this:

```
if has('gui_running')
    " GVim
    set guifont=Larabiefont\ 13
else
    " Vim
    set t_Co=256
    set termguicolors
endif
colorscheme archery
```

Notice the `set termguicolors` in this code. I think this is the most convenient solution nowadays for common issues with colorschemes. It tells Vim to use the true colors defined for GVim with hexadecimal notation in `guifg` and `guibg` (instead of `ctermfg` and `ctermbg`).

Comment: I pasted it in `$MYVIMRC` nothing happened. I inserted `colorscheme tomorrow-night` inside the `else` but it was just black & white

Comment: I have already used this colorscheme in the past. I remember that this was "Tomorrow-Night" (with caps). Is the name spelled correctly?

Comment: still the same. I think the wrong is with `set termguicolors`

Comment: Still the same? What do you mean?

Comment: black and white

Comment: Delete `set termguicolors` and put `syntax on` after your colorscheme declaration. What happens?

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Thanks for your help :)